# Implode array & search for matches mysql php

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to take an `array` and implode it and than run it through a mysql query to search my database for matches. If there are matches, I wanna return the matching values. It keeps returning false and I'm not sure why. I did a `vardump` and can see the array is there, but doesn't seem to be getting passed to the `mysql_query`. If I manually put the array into the query it works no problem. Any ideas?

My Array (This comes from my Android App):

```
$refids = (jdu23764js84, 2746272jsjs7f, 39823874hbsjsk)
```

PHP script code:

```
public function searchList($refids) {
    $refarray = array($refids);        
    $comma_separated = implode(',', $refarray);            
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `ref_id` FROM `main` WHERE `ref_id` IN
    ({$comma_separated})");        
    if ($result == true){  
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);                     
            return $result;                
        } else {
          return false; 
    }
```

Comment: you sure that's an array, not a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to quote the individual values inside your $refids, so you're building

```
... WHERE `ref_id` IN (jdu23764js84, 2746272jsjs7f, ...)
```

and MySQL is interpreting those as field names. In other words, you're suffering from an SQL injection attack vulnerability, and your utter lack of ANY error handling on the database code is preventing from seeing the errors mysql is trying to tell you about:

```
$csv = implode("','", $refarray);
                ^-^-- note the addition of the quotes:

$sql = "SELECT .... `ref_id` IN ('{$csv}')";
                                 ^------^--- again, note the quotes
```

This fixes the problem in the short term. In the long term, you need to read through http://bobby-tables.com and learn what it has to tell you.

Comment: This didn't work. It's not separating the values with individual quotes. It's just creating 'du23764js84, 2746272jsjs7f, 39823874hbsjsk'

Comment: Then you have a string, not an array, and your implode is pointless.

Comment: `array('f,o,o')` doesn't give you an array with 3 elements. it gives you an array with a SINGLE string inside it, which happens to have 3 letters and 2 commas.